# Matar execução do delay() usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando exatamente isso:

`fadeIn(1000)` - `delay(6000)` - `fadeOut(1000)` (8 segundos)

Para exibir um alerta para o usuário, resolvi colocar no próprio alerta um botão para o usuário dar `dismiss`, usando o `fadeOut(300)` mas não funciona.

O `fadeOut` só executa depois do `delay()` terminar, tem como forçar a parada do `delay()` ?

Comment: Neste caso podia postar uma resposta para a pergunta não ficar aberta.

Answer (score 0):

galera consegui, dei uma olhada na `DOC` do `Jquery`, a função `stop()`, mata a fila de execução de animações, só usar: 
`stop().fadeOut(300);` 
que funciona beleza!